# Check whether values in one data frame column exist in a second data frame (with boundaries) in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames (Df1 and Df2)

```
Df1 = [2526480, 14829362, 25874436]
Df2 = [2526450, 14829402, 25874506]
```

None of the values in Df1 and Df2 are the same, but the values in Df2 are within the boundaries of +/- 1000 of the values in Df1

My task is to identify the values in Df2 that are the same (or within the range of +/- 1000) of the values in Df1.]

This is what I have so far:

```
Df1$presentinDf2 <- as.integer(Df1$V2 %in% Df2$V2)
```

This only gives the integer number of values in Df2 that **exactly** match the values in Df1, so I want to set boundaries of some sort. Thanks!

NB: The values I'm interested in are in column "V2" of both dataframes

Comment: Well, `pd.DataFrame` I think is from python and not R. Do you want the solution to be in R or python?

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I'm new to R, I just copied and pasted the example from a previous question to simplify it. Yes, I want the solution in R. Just edit it!

Comment: That is not a valid R code.  Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Also show expected output for the data shared.